# Set icon for Qt application built in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt

I have a Qt application that I've made in Visual Studio however I can't figure out how to create the executable (on windows) with a specific icon instead of the default windows executable icon. Anyone know the simplest way to do this using visual studio or something else?

Edit -
In addition to the answer below this is what I had to do step by step:

- In Visual Studio add the *.rc file to the "Source Files" folder
- In the *.rc file add the line specified in the answer below (also make sure the *.ico file is in same location as the *.rc file).
- After this I just had to run the project in debug mode and restart the PC for the change to take effect.

Comment: See the official docs: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.12/appicon.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know whether this is the Qt-offical way of doing things but this is what works for me:

1. Create a `*.ico` file of whatever you want to use as a logo. I called mine `favicon.ico`.
2. Create a file named `yourapplication.rc`.
3. Add the following line to `yourapplication.rc`: `IDI_ICON1 ICON DISCARDABLE "favicon.ico"`.
4. Add the `*.rc` file to your buildsystem as a source file.
5. Make sure that your `*.exe` ships along side the `favicon.ico` file.

**Edit:** Official Qt5 documentation on this: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/appicon.html

Comment: Do I add that line just anywhere in the .rc file? And by add it as a source file do you mean move the .rc file from the resource file folder in vs to the source files folder? Also I'm still unsure how to make the executable.

Comment: You add that as the first (and only) line in the `*.rc` file. Then add that file to your build system. In case of cmake just add it as a regular private source file. With qmake there is `RC_ICONS`. Check the official documentation linked in my answer for more details.
When you deploy/ship your application the `favicon.ico` file needs to be in the same folder as your executable (`*.exe`).